How to add comments to a Delta Table in Scala?
I would like to add comments to columns of an existing Delta table, without having to actually write SQL statements like "ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN". Is it possible to do it using only Scala?

Why not running spark.sql('<ALTER STATEMNET>') in scala?

You can use MetadataBuilder to change schema of DF after reading table in scala but you need overwrite data.

@MohanaBC spark.sql('ALTER STATEMENT') is exactly what I want to avoid. what's scala about it? almost nothing. I still have to write a SQL statement as a string, have it interpreted, and discover bugs at runtime (ex: typos).

Without spark sql statements, the way to go about are as follows

Create a dataframe from the existing delta table
Change the comment on the column of interest using the withColumn applied on the columns.

An example :
// Load the Delta table
val df = spark.read.format("delta").load("/path/to/delta/table")

// Define the column comments
val columnComments = Map(
  //  column_name -> comment_on_column
  "col_1" -> "comment on col_1",
  "col_2" -> "comment on col_2",
  // ... other columns of interest
)

// Add comments to columns
val dfWithComments = df.schema.fields.foldLeft(df) { (df, field) =>
  df.withColumn(field.name, col(field.name).as(field.name, columnComments.getOrElse(field.name, "")))
}

// Write the DataFrame back to the Delta table
dfWithComments.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/path/to/delta/table")

Only hiccup I would see here is the overwrite operation, which can be expensive and risky for large tables. Better & safer alterntive would be the ALTER TABLE command

I found a solution that fits what I want to do. Here it goes for reference:
import org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.{Identifier, TableCatalog, TableChange}

// the following configuration is not needed in Databricks
val spark = SparkSession.builder
          .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
          .getOrCreate()

val tableCatalog = spark.sessionState.catalogManager.catalog("spark_catalog").asInstanceOf[TableCatalog]
tableCatalog.alterTable(
  Identifier.of(Array("default"), "foo"), // changing table default.foo
  TableChange.updateColumnComment(Array("bar"), "hello") // changing column/field bar to add/update comment
)

TableChange has methods to change a Table or its columns, like:

setProperty
addColumn
deleteColumn
updateColumn
etc

Here is how the table history looks like:
// the table history
// +-------+--------------------+------+--------+-------------+--------------------+----+--------+---------+-----------+--------------+-------------+----------------+------------+--------------------+
// |version|           timestamp|userId|userName|    operation| operationParameters| job|notebook|clusterId|readVersion|isolationLevel|isBlindAppend|operationMetrics|userMetadata|          engineInfo|
// +-------+--------------------+------+--------+-------------+--------------------+----+--------+---------+-----------+--------------+-------------+----------------+------------+--------------------+
// |      2|2024-05-03 21:36:...|  null|    null|CHANGE COLUMN|{column -> {"name...|null|    null|     null|          1|  Serializable|         true|              {}|        null|Apache-Spark/3.4....|
// |      1|2024-05-03 21:36:...|  null|    null|CHANGE COLUMN|{column -> {"name...|null|    null|     null|          0|  Serializable|         true|              {}|        null|Apache-Spark/3.4....|
// |      0|2024-05-03 21:36:...|  null|    null| CREATE TABLE|{isManaged -> fal...|null|    null|     null|       null|  Serializable|         true|              {}|        null|Apache-Spark/3.4....|
// +-------+--------------------+------+--------+-------------+--------------------+----+--------+---------+-----------+--------------+-------------+----------------+------------+--------------------+

